# List lines that consist of a single non-vowel character

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I need to list lines that consist of a single non-vowel character.

I got this:

```
ls | grep -nv '[aeiouy]' file
```

But this doesn't give me a single character. 
How do I get just a single character?

Comment: why are you piping `ls` to `grep` **AND** giving `grep` a filename to process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `x` to match the whole line:

```
grep -nvx '[aeiou]' file.txt
```

Or

```
grep -nv '^[aeiou]$' file.txt
```

Or

```
grep -nx '[^aeiou]' file.txt
```

Or

```
grep -n '^[^aeiou]$' file.txt
```

---

Note that, [parsing `ls` is not a good idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/68757).

Comment: @shawnedward The others should work too..could you please add your input file..